# assert_equal not working with selenium and ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium

I am writing a script using selenium tool in ruby. and I am trying to use assert_equal property of selenium to test pass or failure status of my test. below is my file

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test-unit'

$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
$project_url = "http://www.example.com"

class Travelibro 
  def initialize
    Login.run
  end
end

class Login < 
  @@pop_up_xpath = "/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/p/a"
  @@email_xpath = "//input[@name='user[email]']"
  @@password_xpath = "//input[@name='user[password]']"
  @@click_button_class = "loginBtn"
  @@login_email = "mailtohemant@yahoo.co.in"
  @@login_password = "password"

  def self.run
    login = Login.new
    login.blank_email_or_password
  end

  def blank_email_or_password
    open_login_pop_up = $driver.find_element(:xpath,"#{@@pop_up_xpath}")
    open_login_pop_up.click
    email = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "#{@@email_xpath}")
    email.send_keys "#{@@login_email}"
    password = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "#{@@password_xpath}")
    password.send_keys "#{@@login_password}"
    submit_form = $driver.find_element(:class,"#{@@click_button_class}")
    submit_form.click
    isPresent = $driver.find_elements(:class,"signInError").size() > 0  
    assert_equal($driver.find_elements(:xpath => "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")[0].text, "vin")
    result = {}
    result[:test_name] = "Login Test"
    result[:inputs] = "blank email or password"
    result[:test_result] = isPresent ? "Pass" : "Failed"
    result.each do |key, value|
       puts "#{key}:#{value}"
    end
  end
end
travelibro = Travelibro.new
```

what is the wrong. I am getting this error,

```
/gems/test-unit-3.1.8/lib/test/unit/testcase.rb:430:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Comment: `class Login <` needs a parent class which looks missing here. Also try not to use globals like `$driver` or class instance variables like `@@pop_up_xpath` when a constant like `POP_UP_XPATH` would be better. Quoting strings like `"#{x}"` is likewise redundant and pointless, just put `x` in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create instance of class inherited from Test::Unit::TestCase (I think it's typo that it's empty in code).

The right way to use test-unit gem would be removing Travelibro class, removing Login test construction and renaming blank_email_or_password method to test_black_email_or_password.

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'test-unit'

$driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
$project_url = "http://www.example.com"

class Login < Test::Unit::TestCase
  @@pop_up_xpath = "/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/div[3]/p/a"
  @@email_xpath = "//input[@name='user[email]']"
  @@password_xpath = "//input[@name='user[password]']"
  @@click_button_class = "loginBtn"
  @@login_email = "mailtohemant@yahoo.co.in"
  @@login_password = "password"

  def test_blank_email_or_password
    open_login_pop_up = $driver.find_element(:xpath,"#{@@pop_up_xpath}")
    open_login_pop_up.click
    email = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "#{@@email_xpath}")
    email.send_keys "#{@@login_email}"
    password = $driver.find_element(:xpath, "#{@@password_xpath}")
    password.send_keys "#{@@login_password}"
    submit_form = $driver.find_element(:class,"#{@@click_button_class}")
    submit_form.click
    isPresent = $driver.find_elements(:class,"signInError").size() > 0  
    assert_equal($driver.find_elements(:xpath => "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/a")[0].text, "vin")
    result = {}
    result[:test_name] = "Login Test"
    result[:inputs] = "blank email or password"
    result[:test_result] = isPresent ? "Pass" : "Failed"
    result.each do |key, value|
       puts "#{key}:#{value}"
    end
  end
end
```

Or if you are inheriting not from Test::Unit::TestCase, you can just override constructor, and class will be created successfully

```
def initialize
end
```